# Canon HV20 recognized, but no drivers in Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, firewire

My Canon HV20 camcorder is properly recognized when connected via Firewire to Windows 7 x64, but **no** drivers are installed for it. Windows or I cannot locate any drivers for it as, but it should be working off-the-shelf.

I googled a lot, and found [instructions](http://www.hv20.com/showthread.php?21057-HV20-Connection-on-Windows-7&p=176402&viewfull=1#post176402) to set IEEE 1394 host to legacy mode via Device Manager, but Windows doesn't offer me the legacy option at all. If I check the properties of Canon&HV20 device in Other devices section it says

```
The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28)

There is no driver selected for the device information set or element.
```

It used to work just fine on my previous installation of Vista x64 and same hardware :/

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help - from [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/could-not-see-canon-g10-and-hf11-in-windows-7/5ea0b2df-859f-4c47-b92c-32119a6edc94):

> I had somewhat similar problem with G10.  Turns out I had Windows 7 Ultimate N installed.  This version does not necessarily include multimedia support as per the EU court case or something like that.  After installing Microsoft update patch that restores the missing multimedia files, the camera was immediately recognized when connecting to USB.
>
> [Media Feature Pack for Windows 7 N and Windows 7 KN (KB968211)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=31017ed3-166a-4c75-b90c-a6cef9b414c4)
>
> Now when ZoomBrowser opens I can connect to camera etc.

Comment: No, had regular, that pack won't install. I've since reinstalled whole OS and now it just works.

Answer (score 0):

Drivers should be found at

http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/camcorders/high_definition_camcorders/vixia_hv20#DriversAndSoftware

Comment: "No drivers are available for this selection. This operating system may not require a driver or, in the case of older operating systems, may no longer be supported."